# URL Rewrite using DNS only

Tags: dns

i know you can't redirect the path portion of a URL with DNS only

But is this possible with DNS only?

app1.domain.com --> domain.com:4993
app2.domain.com --> domain.com:4994

(both are https only)

which DNS records do i need to add?

Comment: Your first two sentences seem to contradict each other. You know it is not possible with DNS only and then you ask how to do it with DNS only. You may wish to edit that, and also use `example.com` for your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with pure DNS. The DNS does not care about the port, but only about the domain. To achieve this check if your DNS provider offers Web Redirecting or Web Forwarding. It's not DNS only, but depending on the reason why you want it to be DNS only this might work for you.